# Laravel 5.8 - Listagem de relacionamento

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte código no meu controller `funcionarios::with('user', 'rh')->get()`retorna todos dados relacionados bonito mas somente o primeiro registro está realmente relacionado certo os demais no relacionamento RH não lista os dados do RH vem sem nada um array vazio.

Segue o código da model:

```
class funcionarios extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'funcionarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'sexo',
        'celular',
        'matricula',
        'ramal'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];


    public function rh()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\RH::class, 'funcionario_rh', 'rh_id', 'funcionario_id');

    }

    public function user() {

        return $this->hasOne(\App\User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Deixo alertado que os cadastros estão corretos no banco da forma que devem ser feita e ta cadastrando certinho tudo, o real problema é na listagem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvi já, fiz um erro no relacionamento do Laravel o código que coloquei na pergunta tem uma inversão em `RH_id` e `funcionario_id`trocando os dois de lugar a listagem flui perfeitamente.